# i'm unable to call the parent function from within iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

i've seen the other posts in regard to this, but the following method is not working for some reason.

```
onclick="parent.testing();"
```

now for the full story. i have an index.html that houses all the JS files. also within the index, i have an empty 'div' tag. with jQuery, i'm appending a page1.html file to the empty 'div'. so the index kinda looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script files>
<script>
ready { function testing(){do stuff;} }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><iframe src="page1.html" (added via jQuery)></div>
</body>
</html>
```

now in the page1.html file, i'm trying to call a function when a link is clicked. but i'm receiving the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'testing' of undefined
```

i've also tried the following but they didn't work:

```
onclick="window.testing();"
onclick="window.frames[0].testing();"
```

Comment: What error does it give you when you use `parent.testing()`. That is the correct approach. You also don't need to declare you  `function`'s in a ready block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent page script isn't valid JavaScript, but assuming `ready { ... }`:

```
<script>
ready { function testing(){do stuff;} }
</script>
```

...is a simplification supposed to represent a document ready handler you are declaring `testing()` as a local function within that ready handler so it can only be accessed from within that ready handler. You need to make `testing()` global in the parent page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready({ /* your on ready stuff here */ });

function testing(){ /* do stuff; */ }
</script>
```

...and then you should be able to call it from the iframe using `parent.testing()`.

Comment: thank you! this worked. i thought i had it setup right because doesn't the jQuery Document Ready load first before the JavaScript onLoad?

Comment: The document ready should happen before onload, but your problem isn't a question of _timing,_ it's a question of _scope._

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, your problem it's your function is not called, right? So maybe a solution is to put this in your "page1.html"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="your_js_file"></script>
```

Comment: nnnnn was able to answer my question. i thought about doing this way as well. but i didn't want to have the script sources spread out into the iframed pages. my goal is to have a set of global scripts hosted in the index, and then each iframe can call whichever one it wants to.

Comment: Yes it's a better solution when you have more than one iframe in your page, you're right.